# How to select several string values of the same variable

Tags: spss

I want to select several countries (cases) from a `sav` file using `SPSS`.
I tried

```
ANY(cntry, 'Belgium','Denmark','Germany','Ireland','Spain','France','Italy','Netherlands', 'Austria', 'Portugal', 'Finland', 'Sweden', 'United Kingdom')
```

but I got zero cases.

I also tried

```
(cntry = 'Belgium') OR (cntry = 'Denmark') ....
```

But `VARIABLE LABELS` became too long with more than 256 bytes,

Comment: What you describe seems strange - it should have worked... Please edit your post to add a small sample of your data and the full syntax of your commad so we can reproduce the problem and try to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I was using variable labels instead a variable values i.e. 'Belgium' instead of 'BE'.

Comment: If you already have lists ready with names instead of numbers, you can get a table of values and labels from `display dictionary`, match it to your data, and then you'll be able to use the commands you tried.